# perl - printing text in excel spreadsheet

Tags: perl

TEXT FILE

```
malloc
calloc
free
```

.C source file

MY CODE

```
my $word_search_path = $ENV{'SCRIPT_PATH'}."\\word_search.txt";
open(FILE1, "< $word_search_path") or die $!;
chomp(my @words = <FILE1>);
close(FILE1);

my $input = $ARGV[0];
open(FILE, $input) or die $!;                              #source file
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

my $temp_path =  $ENV{'TEMPLOG'}."\\dynamic_alloc_log.csv";
open(FILE2, "> $temp_path") or die "couldn't open the file!";

foreach my $word(@words){
   my $count = 0;
   foreach(@lines){
     if($_ =~ $word){
          $count++;
     }
   } 
    print FILE2 $word. $count."\n";
 }
 close(FILE2);
```

OUTPUT I GET

```
malloc0       #in 1st field
calloc1       #in 2nd field
free2
```

OUTPUT I NEED

```
malloc    0      # malloc in one field , 0 in next field
calloc    1 
free      2
```

it will be great if i can do without any Perl modules. One more thing TEXT FILE data are user defined.So its not fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your print statement to

```
print FILE2 "${word},${count}\n";
```

Or

```
printf FILE2 "%s,%s\n", $word, $count;
```

Since you're already storing output to `.csv` file, it should display fields properly in `MS Excel`

Comment: works fine. It was simple. Just didn't struck my mind.bit in hurry also as I have to finish this by today